# .Net vector drawing SDK

Tags: .net, vector, sdk, drawing, autocad

I'm currently working on a project which must be able to design UPVC windows and doors. I'm looking for a SDK which can draw lines, rectangles, etc as Objects. User should be able to change the dimensions and the software should automatically calculates the angles, re sizing effects on other shapes area and circumference. All objects are 2D. Screenshots of RA Workshop as a good example. I prefer .Net programming and using a SDK instead of creating my own engine.

[Ra Workshop Official Website](http://www.raworkshop.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AutoCAD .Net API can definitely do this for you.  If you're looking to package it into your own application you'll be looking at a considerable cost to license AutoCAD for each installation.